# SIMD load in loop with descending index

Tags: vectorization, simd

I am just wondering how SIMD extensions implement the vector load in loop with descending index.

For example we have a loop of
for(i = N; i ==0; i--)

But the consecutive memory is loaded from low address. In such situation, is the vector load followed by a vector shuffle to place each element to the correct lane?

Thanks in advance,
T

Comment: It's not incorrect to load the "normal way around" when looping backwards.

Comment: No, there's no reason to shuffle.  It doesn't matter which element is in which lane, unless you want to do a horizontal operation.